# quantity of members allowed in sharepoint

Tags: membership-provider

how many members can I have in the SharePoint $20/month subscription?  Can each member add new files to my folders?
this is a beginners question.

Answer (score 0):

Its totally depends on the plan.

For SharePoint Online Plan 1, it should be $5 user/month

SharePoint Online Plan 2, it should be $10 user/month

Office 365 Enterprise E3, it should be $20 user/month